# Django session aren't updated

Tags: python, django, session

I have question about django sessions. I update session using `SessionStore` out of view, but `request.session` is same (in settings `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True`).

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: s = SessionStore(session_key='mysessionkey')
s['name'] = 'myname'
s.save()
print s.items() # there is my name key
print request.session.items() # but not here...
why ?

Comment: Did you actually create the session? In other words, something like `s['last_login'] = 1376587691` then `s.create()`?

Comment: I will try. Thanks

Comment: As i know create() add new row in sessions table.

Comment: Edit your question with all relevant information about what you are actually doing and what is going wrong please.